# jQuery DatePicker Not Working

Tags: jquery, asp.net, datepicker

I'm trying to implement the jQuery datepicker from http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#default.

This site provides various JS and CSS files that I can include. However, I'm already including the following standard jQuery files. Can anyone tell me what needs to be included beyond these standard files?

```
<link href="/css/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/css/jquerySliderOverride.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/javascript/jquery/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/javascript/jquery/jquery-ui-1.8.7.custom.min.js"></script>
```

As it is, no calendar appears. Here's my markup:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#<%= DateTextBox.ClientID %>datepicker").datepicker();
    });
</script>
```

And...

```
<div class="demo"><asp:textbox runat="server" id="DateTextBox" /></div>
```

Comment: I don't think your ID is going to be correct in your jQuery selector. I think it should just be `$("#<%= DateTextBox.ClientID %>").datepicker();`

Comment: Did you customize the jquery ui when you dl'd it? You can leave out the datepicker and that might have happened. Try linking to the full jquery ui js and see if it works. https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.14/jquery-ui.min.js

Comment: @jen: Looks like it was just a typo, but the format still isn't quite right. As I attempted to explain, I don't want to download any custom stuff that might be already included in the standard files. The site doesn't seem to have a lot of information about avoiding duplicate content that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think your ID is going to be correct in your jQuery selector. It should just be

```
$(function () {    
    $("#<%= DateTextBox.ClientID %>").datepicker();
});
```

In the example that you have linked to, they use the id `datepicker` but you don't have to :) (the datepicker plugin adds the `hasDatepicker` CSS class).

Comment: D'oh. Can't believe I missed that! Yeah, I now get the calendar, although it looks like I need to tweak the styling.

Answer (score 2):

You should do this instead :

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $( "#<%= DateTextBox.ClientID %>" ).datepicker();
});
</script>
```